# Connect to multiple Wireless networks with single adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, wifi-configuration

I need to connect to multiple wireless networks but I only have one adapter, I have windows 8 and I find on google that can be done using Virtual WiFi, but I dont know how to enable a virtual adapter to connect to another wireless network.

Is there a better way to connect to multiple wireless networks, if not, how can I enable a "Virtual WiFi adapter" on Windows 8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) will work for you. Using this you can assign different network to different apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) or [MyPublicWifi](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Please explain *how* to use them to accomplish the task.